# Creating and debugging a Sharepoint Services 3.0 WebPart

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint

I am trying to create a WebPart for my locally installed Sharepoint Services 3.0 and I've followed various tips and guides to get it all working. However somewhere on the road I must have missed something or this is just not "in all the books".

When creating an empty Sharepoint WebPart and just hitting F5 to debug it, I get the following message:

> Error 1   The HTTP request is
>   unauthorized with client
>   authentication scheme 'Negotiate'. The
>   authentication header received from
>   the server was 'Negotiate,NTLM'.      0   0

And as [this article from microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/215383) suggests I did enable Negotiate, NTLM. But it's still not working,

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by removing Sharepoint Services 3.0 and Re-installing it using the Sharepoint Services 3.0 SP2 installation.

Which then gave me another error telling me that the URI was Null which lead me to [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/59c39b6a-a83e-4716-8a0f-cffdcec3bb68).

**Conclusion**

Install Visual Studio Sharepoint Tools 1.2 instead of 1.3 CTP solved everything.

Comment: That's weird... I have found the VSeWSS 1.3CTP to be way better than the 1.2 version